# NuxtJS 3 Generates draft content

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-content

I am developing a blog site based on **Nuxt JS** content and **Markdown**. In my post's markdown frontmatter if I specify `draft: true` it was supposed to generate that post *only in development mode* according to the [doc](https://content.nuxt.com/usage/markdown#native-parameters). The doc says:

> `draft` | `boolean` | Mark the page as draft (and only display it in development mode).

Thus, when I run `npm run dev`, the draft post gets generated; which is fine.

But when I run `npm run generate`, it also generates the **draft** posts in the `.output` directory. How can I tell Nuxt not to generate the draft post for `generate` command?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, open for about a year now: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/1523